# switch store view with select country in checkout / cart

Tags: checkout, cart, store-view, countries, store-switcher

I would like to trigger the store view to change according to the selected country in cart and checkout in Magento 2.4.3

Does anyone do have a clue if or how this is possible?

Thanks